# Show sequence $\{\frac{s_{n}}{n}\}$ converges provided $s_{m + n} \leq s_{m} + s_{n}, s_{n} \geq 0$ for all $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Provided hint is to let $a = \lim \inf \frac{s_{n}}{n}$, then show $\frac{s_{n}}{n} \rightarrow a$.

Need help understanding provided solution:

> From assumption, $s_{m_1 + m_2 + \cdots + m_k} \leq s_{m_1} + \cdots + s_{m_k}$ is true. Let $b = \lim \sup \frac{s_n}{n}, a = \lim \inf \frac{s_n}{n}$. Suppose $b - a = t > 0$. Take $\epsilon = \frac{t}{3}$. By definition of $a, b$ there exists a constant $N$ so that $\frac{s_{N}}{N} \leq a + \epsilon$. Also, given any $k \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists $m > kN$ so that $\frac{s_m}{m} \geq b - \epsilon$. We can write $m = k_1 N + N_1$, where $N_1 < N, k_1 \geq k$. Therefore, $s_m \geq k_1 N \frac{s_m}{m} \geq k_1 N(b - \epsilon)$. On the other hand, $s_m \leq k_1 s_{N} + s_{N_1} \leq k_1 N(a + \epsilon) + s_{N_1}$. Note $N_1 < N$ is bounded. There is a contradiction when $k \rightarrow \infty$.

My understanding ends starting from "By definition...". My understanding of definitions of $\lim \sup$'s and $\lim \inf$'s is that given $\epsilon > 0$, $\exists N$ such that $n > N$ implies

$$a - \epsilon < \frac{s_n}{n} < b + \epsilon,$$

which does not seem to agree with statement in solution that "$\exists \frac{s_{N}}{N} \leq a + \epsilon$" from definition. Please help resolve this confusion as well as provide an explanation for rest of solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We have $(k_1N)(b-\epsilon)/m \leq s_m/m\leq ((k_1N)(a+\epsilon)+o(1))/m$ where $o(1)\to 0$ as $k\to\infty$ (and therefore as $m\to\infty$). This is a contradiction because in the limit as $k\to\infty$, we have $b \leq a+2\epsilon/3$, which contradicts the fact that $b\geq a+\epsilon$.